# How to make a background image transparent in the activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use an `Activity` which has normal views and controls.

I made the background of it as an image and I can't make this image transparent
Here's my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/honey"
 >
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want just the image to be transparent

Comment: You want the whole background to be transparent? You want to see through the background? That doesn't make any sense to me. Something has to be behind it if it's transparent. You probably want a *translucent* image on top of the background, not as the background.

Comment: Yes I want a translucent image which infront of it is the buttons and other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for transparent background:

in the file AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity" android:theme="@style/TransparentStyle"></activity>
```

in the file /res/values/style.xml

```
<resources>
  <style name="TransparentStyle">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
    <item name ="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and try this for transparent image:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
  android:alpha=".75"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. it worked, but androidwindowbackground wasn't acceptable to the app so I deleted this line. Can you tell me about its importance